# How to get all employees belonging to a head as the structure shown in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

For example 201 the employee can see the 301, 302; 401, 402 and 403 to be 302 subordinates. This n levels

```
     ID_EMPLOYEE   ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS     LEVEL
    -------------------------------------------
        100           NULL                1
        201           100                 2
        202           100                 2
        301           201                 3
        302           201                 3
        303           202                 3
        304           202                 3
        401           302                 4
        402           302                 4
        403           302                 4
        N             N-1                 N
```

With response Julien Vavasseur I can know who are the subordinates of a specific employee. But now I want to know the total sales of immediate subordinate, how could you do it?
the structure is as follows:

```
ID_EMPLOYEE       SALE
401               1100.00
402               1500.00
403               1400.00
303               5000.00
304               8250.00
```

For example for the employee 100 can see

```
ID_EMPLOYEE  SALES  
201           4000
202          13250
```

This n levels

Comment: This can be solved using a recursive cte. There are literally thousands and thousands of examples of this around this site and the rest of the internet. It has been answered over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already millions of questions about recursive CTE on this site and online and they all teach you how to write this type of query:

```
Declare @data table(ID_EMPLOYEE int, ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS int, LEVEL int)
insert into @data(ID_EMPLOYEE, ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS, LEVEL) values
    (100, NULL, 1)
    , (201, 100, 2)
    , (202, 100, 2)
    , (301, 201, 3)
    , (302, 201, 3)
    , (303, 202, 3)
    , (304, 202, 3)
    , (401, 302, 4)
    , (402, 302, 4)
    , (403, 302, 4);

with cte(n, ID_EMPLOYEE) as (
    Select 0, ID_EMPLOYEE From @data Where ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS = 201
    Union All
    Select n+1, d.ID_EMPLOYEE From @data d
    Inner Join cte c on c.ID_EMPLOYEE = d.ID_EMPLOYEE_BOSS
)
Select * 
From cte c
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

On technet: [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)